# Why counter not increase on function argument via method

Tags: go

I try writing simple counter but I don't understand why he didn't work.. There is my code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Count int

type Counter interface {
    Next()
    Prev()
    Jump(j int) //i want increase Count to 'j' value
}

func (c *Count) Next() { *c += 1 }
func (c *Count) Prev() { *c -= 1 }
func (c *Count) Jump(j int) { *c += j } //Here Error

func main() {
    val := new(Count) //0
    val.Next() //+1
    val.Jump(4) //+4
    val.Prev() //-1
    fmt.Println("Now ", *val) //expected 4
}
```

Is anybody knows what the problem here?
Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the Jump signature:

```
Jump(j Count)
```

And you will get the expected result.

See <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/-nU4k_-U9L)</kbd>

If you don't, you would get:

```
prog.go:15: invalid operation: *c += j (mismatched types Count and int)
 [process exited with non-zero status]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works fine, but will you can (in two words) explain to me why needed wrote 'Count' instead `int`? Sorry, I'm start learning now ;)

Comment: @ZaNoza go doesn't do automatic conversion between types: http://golang.org/doc/faq#conversions. That means you must use the same type.

Comment: Ahh. Bingo! Count != int. Thanks again, @VonC! Now I understand more than 2 hours ago. )